# colliding 2 moving and rotating sprites in xna 2d

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7

I recently started making a game in windows phone XNA, I have a rocket in the middle that I can rotate and has a thrust to speed up in the direction it is facing and meteors coming out. The point is to survive as long as you can and avoid collision with the meteors. I can't manage to implement the collision between two moving and rotating sprites which are the rocket and a random meteor. I've seen rectangular collision which to me appears bad but maybe I am coding it a bit wrong and the pixel collision is way complicated :/ any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You're right on that main point: **pixel collision is way complicated**. Often times, it's going to be far, far more effort than it's worth. You'll likely have to program a form of collision that's not 100% the same as the visuals you draw. A rocket sounds like something that could very easily use rectangle collision detection. However, a random guess suggests the meteors are more circular. Actually, **circle** collision detection is also pretty basic; for instance, circle-to-circle collision just involves calculating the distance between two objects, and comparing their radii (plural of radius)

This involves a bit of math; I think for the progress of your game development skills, it would be good to try to understand what's happening here, or even look up some textbooks on the subject; but if you get a basic grasp of what goes in and what comes out, you may just be able to drop it into your code...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443845/the-maths-for-2d-collision-detection-between-an-obb-and-a-circle

(Oriented means having some form of rotation. Bounding box is a fancy name for a rectangle.)

Comment: Now that I look at it, I think that code sample in the link may not suit your needs. Someone else links to Wikipedia, and Seperating Axis seems like the correct thing to use - I just haven't worked with collision detection in a while, so I hadn't remembered the name of the correct formula to use for box <-> circle.

Comment: can you give me an example of rectangular collision of moving and/or rotating sprites?

Comment: A few links that may help: http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/rotatedrectanglecollisions/rotatedrectanglecollisions.shtml http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html (The second link is what I used for collision detection when I was in college!) A few changes are needed for your specific implementations.